# How to execute a CMD file in remote computer

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am looking to execute a command in remote machine using invoke but the .cmd file will call for additional .vbs script. So i guess i may have to mention CScript if so how do i mention both cmd/c and cscript in the below command

`Invoke-Command -computername blrscrv01 -ScriptBlock { param($path, $command ) cmd /c $path $command } -args '"C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe"','"/?"'`

Comment: Modified Script Option1
`param( [string]$ComputerName, [string]$User, [string]$pass ) 
Get-PSSEssion | Remove-PSSession
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
param(
[string]$ComputerName,
[string]$Username,
[string]$Password
)
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("k:", "\\lcsap027\deploy", $false, $Username, $Password)
Invoke-command -computername $computername -scriptblock {cmd/c "k:c2.cmd"} -args 'c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe' , '/?'
$net.RemoveNetworkDrive("k:")
} -args $ComputerName,$User,$pass
`

Comment: Error Message Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following err
or occured while using Kerberos authentication: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.  
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specified.

Answer (score 0):

Your example worked for me when I removed the extra level of quoting.

```
Invoke-Command -computername blrscrv01 -ScriptBlock { param($path, $command ) cmd /c $path $command } -args 'C:\windows\system32\cscript.exe','/?'
```

### Troubleshooting

Enter a remote session and poke around.

```
Enter-PSSession -computername blrscrv01
```

Verify that the target script exists and is accessible.

```
dir \\lcsap027\deploy\c2.cmd
dir \\lcsap027\deploy
type \\lcsap027\deploy\c2.cmd
```

Attempt to run the script interactively.

```
\\lcsap027\deploy\c2.cmd
```

or

```
cmd /c \\lcsap027\deploy\c2.cmd
```

#### Alternative

Another thing you might try is not invoking a cmd script remotely, but issuing the commands remotely. `New-PSSession` will return a handle you can use to deal interactively with the remote machine. You can repeatedly issue commands with `Invoke-Command` and get the results (as primitive data types and generic objects, though, not the actual objects themselves).

### Altered Script

Here's an altered version of the script you put in your comment. I've removed the nested `Invoke-Command` (I don't know why it was necessary, you're already running commands on the remote machine). Since the line breaks got lost in the comment, I don't know if there were any statement separator problems (I'll just assume there weren't, though in its "formatted" form as a one-liner, it would have died horribly because PoSH wouldn't have known where one statement ended and the next began).

```
param(
  [string]$ComputerName,
  [string]$User,
  [string]$pass
)

Get-PSSEssion | Remove-PSSession    
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
  param(
    [string]$ComputerName,
    [string]$Username,
    [string]$Password
  )

  $net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
  $net.MapNetworkDrive("x:", "\\machinename\sharename", $false, $Username, $Password)
  cmd.exe /c "x:\c2.cmd"

  $net.RemoveNetworkDrive("x:")
} -args $ComputerName, $User, $pass
```

This at least got the remote script to run and produced the expected output. (I emitted the computer name, user name, and file location.)

Bear in mind that this method doesn't employ any transport-/application-layer encryption, so the password is sent cleartext over the network.

Comment: Below is my error message `The term \\lcsap027\deploy\c2.cmd is not recognized as the name of the cmdlet` I have the variable $path = \\lcsap027\deploy and $command = c2.cmd. Where is my mistake

Comment: I don't know why you're not concatenating the path and command together then: `$path\$command`, or just giving the path to the .CMD script as a single parameter.

Comment: Either way, accessing shares from the remote session does not seem to work implicitly. You can verify what the environment looks like by using Enter-PSSession to get an (almost) interactive shell and inspecting the environment. If you try to access a remote share that way, (in my experience), you'll get rejected. I get "access denied" around here. I have to issue a `net use` command (with password embedded in the command) to map remote drives. I don't have a good answer for why this behavior exists, but it certainly seems to be the case whether I can find docs or not.

Comment: i agree with you and hence i modified the script as below, and still i am unable to achieve what i want. Due to space issues i have included the modified script in my original question

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, then.

Comment: can u please let me know how to execute a cmd file which may call for .vbs field in a local computer. What i am trying to do is that, due to security restrictions i am unable to use psexec and wsman hence i am planning to copy the scripts to the local computer and invoke a normal .bat which will inturn execute the copied file

Comment: In my experience, you either have to copy the files locally or send your password over the network (via psexec). Unless the files themselves contain sensitive information, copying them is probably the best solution.

Comment: hi unfortunately due to security reasons i can transfer neither copy files due to size limitations

Comment: It sounds like the only option left to you is to send your password over the wire to map a remote (relative the remote machine) location. You could make this un-horrible by requiring HTTPS for WS-MAN, but it would probably require reconfiguring the remote machine (at least, issuing it a server certificate).